# Polars conditional merge of rows

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have some time data, that I want to merge if two intervals are close enough (and the type is the same), currently I'm doing sth. like this:

Note: *time_start, time_end* are datetimes, *type* a categorical string

```py
buffer = dt.timedelta(minutes=15)
_temp_df = (
    data.sort("time_start").select([
        pl.col("*"),
        ((pl.col("time_start").shift(-1)) - pl.col("time_end")).fill_null(0).apply(lambda x: (dt.timedelta(seconds=x // 1000))).alias("offset"),
        pl.col("type").shift(-1).alias("type_next")
    ]).select([
        pl.col("time_start"), pl.col("time_end"), pl.col("type"),
        ((pl.col("offset") < buffer) & (pl.col("type") == pl.col("type_next"))).alias("can_merge")
    ])
).to_dicts()

_after_df = []
if len(_temp_df) != 0:
    last_data = _temp_df[0]
    for i in range(1, len(_temp_df)):
        _dp = _temp_df[i]
        if last_data['can_merge']:
            last_data['time_end'] = _dp['time_end']
            last_data['can_merge'] = _dp['can_merge']
        else:
            _after_df.append(last_data)
            last_data = _dp

    _after_df.append(last_data)

data = pl.from_dicts(_after_df)
```

Whilst this works, it feels extremely off, that I have to convert `polars -> dicts -> polars`, is there a way to do this over the aggregations? The `groupby_dynamic` and `grouby_rolling` seem to only accepts times, but I want to merge consecutive rows by offset.

This is Polars: 0.13.59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide any data, so let's start with the following:

```py
import datetime as dt
import polars as pl

data = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "time_start": [ "12:00", "12:20", "12:40", "13:10", "13:15", "13:50", "13:55", "14:50", "15:20", ],
            "time_end": [ "12:15", "12:30", "13:00", "13:20", "13:45", "14:00", "14:45", "15:00", "15:30", ],
            "type": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a"],
        }
    )
).with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("type").cast(pl.Categorical),
        pl.format("2020-01-01T{}:00", "time_start")
        .str.strptime(pl.Datetime())
        .dt.cast_time_unit("ms")
        .alias("time_start"),
        pl.format("2020-01-01T{}:00", "time_end")
        .str.strptime(pl.Datetime())
        .dt.cast_time_unit("ms")
        .alias("time_end"),
    ]
)
data
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ time_start          ┆ time_end            ┆ type │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[ms]        ┆ datetime[ms]        ┆ cat  │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 12:15:00 ┆ a    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 12:20:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 12:30:00 ┆ a    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 12:40:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:00:00 ┆ a    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:10:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:20:00 ┆ b    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:15:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:45:00 ┆ b    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:50:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 14:00:00 ┆ c    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:55:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 14:45:00 ┆ c    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 14:50:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 15:00:00 ┆ a    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 15:20:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 15:30:00 ┆ a    │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

##### The Algorithm

**Assumption**: the following should work **as long as no interval fully encloses another**.  The intervals can overlap and they can be disjoint.  (This is why it's helpful if you provide sample data for your question -- it provides some insight as to the assumptions underlying the data.)

```py
(
    data
    .sort("time_start")
    .with_columns([
        (
            (
                pl.col("time_end").dt.offset_by("15m") <
                pl.col("time_start").shift(-1)
            ) |
            (
                pl.col('type') != pl.col('type').shift(-1)
            )
        )
        .shift_and_fill(1, False)
        .cumsum()
        .alias("run_nbr"),
    ])
    .groupby('run_nbr')
    .agg([
        pl.col('time_start').min().alias('time_start'),
        pl.col('time_end').max().alias('time_end'),
        pl.col('type').first().alias('type'),
    ])
    .sort('time_start')
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ run_nbr ┆ time_start          ┆ time_end            ┆ type │
│ ---     ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ u32     ┆ datetime[ms]        ┆ datetime[ms]        ┆ cat  │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 0       ┆ 2020-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:00:00 ┆ a    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1       ┆ 2020-01-01 13:10:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:45:00 ┆ b    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 2020-01-01 13:50:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 14:45:00 ┆ c    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 2020-01-01 14:50:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 15:00:00 ┆ a    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4       ┆ 2020-01-01 15:20:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 15:30:00 ┆ a    │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

Your code gives the same result when you run it.  (I left `run_nbr` in for the discussion below.)  Note: your code converts `type` from `Categorical` to `str`, but the above algorithm maintains it as `Categorical`.

##### In Steps

The algorithm attempts to assign "run numbers" to the sorted intervals.  A "run" of intervals is any successive set of rows that can be collapsed into a single row, based on gap between the intervals and `type`.

```py
(
    data
    .sort("time_start")
    .with_columns([
        (
            (
                pl.col("time_end").dt.offset_by("15m") <
                pl.col("time_start").shift(-1)
            ) |
            (
                pl.col('type') != pl.col('type').shift(-1)
            )
        )
        .shift_and_fill(1, False)
        .cumsum()
        .alias("run_nbr"),
    ])
)
```

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ time_start          ┆ time_end            ┆ type ┆ run_nbr │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ datetime[ms]        ┆ datetime[ms]        ┆ cat  ┆ u32     │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 12:15:00 ┆ a    ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 12:20:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 12:30:00 ┆ a    ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 12:40:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:00:00 ┆ a    ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:10:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:20:00 ┆ b    ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:15:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 13:45:00 ┆ b    ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:50:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 14:00:00 ┆ c    ┆ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 13:55:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 14:45:00 ┆ c    ┆ 2       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 14:50:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 15:00:00 ┆ a    ┆ 3       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2020-01-01 15:20:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 15:30:00 ┆ a    ┆ 4       │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴─────────┘
```

From there, the `groupby` does the rest.

Comment: I've edited the algorithm to use `offset_by`, which is somewhat more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's indeed what I was looking for, I was off my laptop and couldn't copy paste the data